# C# use the VisualDesigner for controls inherited from Tabs or Panels

Tags: c#, user-controls, visualdesigner

Referring to VS2022 and WinForms apps and the Visual Designer.

I would like to create a user control which inherits from a TabPage or Panel, but as soon as I change it from UserControl to TabPage or Panel I can no longer view it on the Visual Designer (the 'canvas' if you will), so I can place my controls on them and design visually.

Is there any way to workaround this behavior?

I also tried setting the attribute to DesignerCategory("Form") or to DesignerCategory("Component") but didn't do the trick.

As a workaround I can use a true UserControl and then place it on top of the actual tabPage, but looks kind of annoying just to be able to visually edit it, so decided to ask if anyone else found a solution